# Searching the list using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, multiprocessing

Here is an example code that checks for the existence of an item in the list and writes it to another list of `a`:

```
list_1 = [(0,1),(3,2),(1,5),(0,3),(3,7)]

a = []
for i in list_1:
    if i[0]==3:
       a.append(i)
       break
```

Output:

```
[(3, 2)]
```

The loop is to be terminated when the first element satisfying the condition found.

Assuming that list `list_1` is very large, how can multiprocessing be applied in such a case?

Comment: How large are we talking about?  Multiprocessing *can* help here, but it's not clear whether the massive increase in complexity is warranted.

Comment: Actually the more I think about it the more I realize this is a data structure problem not a multiprocessing problem.  Don't use a list in the first place.

Comment: generally this will be searching, for example, values from `list(itertools.product (tuple (range (64)), repeat = 4))`, and larger.

Comment: If the first match stops the search, this has to be sequential, and in that case multiprocessing is not the answer. If it's _any_ first match, that's a different story. Anyway, I tend to agree with @wim, this is more of a data structure problem than multiprocessing.

Comment: in my real case, this is not about the problem of data structure, but the fact that in my algorithm there is a bottleneck in the form of a more extensive `if` condition, which in combination with a large list to search gives poor results. that's why I gave only a simplified problem so that nobody would need to bite into the whole sense of the code unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Brake your big list into smaller lists
>>> big= [(0,1),(3,2),(1,5),(0,3),(3,7)]
>>> a=big[0:2]
>>> b=big[2:]
define a function to look for your tuple and return it or return None
>>> def doit(L):
        for i in L:
            if i[0]==3:
                return i
        return None
figure out how to create a new process and call it with each of the smaller lists
>>> doit(a)
(3, 2)
>>> doit(b)
(3, 7)
look at the tuples returned that are not None in order and choose the first one
```

Comment: cool and legible. can you now parallel `doit (a)` and `doit (b)`? and so that it would break the calculation if one of them returns non-empty value. because in this way I will not gain time. I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

@Marichyasana is a very good solution.  I went a little overboard in answering your question and tested multiple pool sizes.  The code is about 114 lines that you can use this as a base to deviate from.

I'm testing multiple `Pool()` sizes of a list of 100,000 samples.  I don't think my code is very "Pythonic" and any feedback would be great.  I used this [example](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/08/02/python-201-a-multiprocessing-tutorial/).

**Results:**

> number of processes: 3; process time is: 00:00:01
>    length of
>   results list 1000
>
> number of processes: 10; process time is: 00:00:02
>    length of
>   results list 1000
>
> number of processes: 20; process time is: 00:00:09
>  length of
>   results list 1000
>
> number of processes: 33; process time is: 00:00:04
>  length of
>   results list 1000

**Code:**

```
# from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Pool
from random import randint
from Timer import Timer # custom timer wraper I wrote

def create_list_indexes(m_int_list_len):
    """
    this method creates as many evenly spaces segments for the list of data

    m_int_list_len
    type: int
    desc: length of the list of data; number of samples of data

    returns
    type: list
    desc: list of lists; indexes for data list
    list_return[x][0] -> type: int; low index
    list_return[x][1] -> type: int; high index
    """
    # segment length    
    int_seg_len = 100
    list_return = list()

    # get number of segments fo the list
    if m_int_list_len % int_seg_len == 0:
        int_num_seg = int(m_int_list_len / int_seg_len)
        bool_zero_mod = True
    else:
        int_num_seg = int(m_int_list_len / int_seg_len) + 1
        bool_zero_mod = False

    # create indexes of list
    for int_i in range(0, int_num_seg):        
        # check for zero mod
        if ~bool_zero_mod and int_i == int_num_seg - 1:
            int_low = int_i * int_seg_len       
            int_high = m_int_list_len
        else:
            int_low = int_i * int_seg_len
            int_high = int_low + int_seg_len - 1

        list_return.append([int_low, int_high])

    return list_return

def test_pools(m_tuple_args):
    """
    this method tests the different number of pools on a large list of data

    m_list_tasks
    type: list
    desc: list of tuples
    m_tuple_args[0] -> type: int; target to search for
    m_tuple_args[1] -> type: list; list of indexes
        m_tuple_args[1][0] -> type: int; low index
        m_tuple_args[1][1] -> type: int; high index    
    m_tuple_args[2] -> type: list; the data

    returns
    type: list
    desc: list of lists; samples which are lists of length 2
    """

    # unpack tuple for simplicity
    int_target = m_tuple_args[0]
    int_low, int_high = m_tuple_args[1]
    list_data = m_tuple_args[2]

    list_results = list()
    for list_sample in list_data[int_low:int_high]:
        if list_sample == int_target:
            list_results.append(list_sample)

    # return results
    return list_results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # data structures for example
    list_data = list()
    list_proc = [3, 10, 20, 33]
    int_num_data = 100000
    int_max_int = 100
    int_target = 42

    # create random data list
    for int_i in range(0, int_num_data):
        list_data.append([randint(0, int_max_int),
                          randint(0, int_max_int)])

    # pools of different sizes to compare
    list_pools = [Pool(processes = x) for x in list_proc]

    # create indexes for list
    list_indexes = create_list_indexes(int_num_data)    

    # compare pools
    int_counter = 0
    for pool in list_pools:
        # create task list
        list_tasks = list()
        for int_i in range(0, len(list_indexes)):
            list_tasks.append((int_target, list_indexes[int_i], list_data))

        # test pool
        timer_pool = Timer()
        list_pool = pool.map(test_pools, list_tasks)
        string_pool = 'number of processes: ' + str(list_proc[int_counter])
        timer_pool.stop_timer(string_pool)
        print('length of results list', len(list_pool))
        print()

        # increment counter
        int_counter += 1
```

Comment: Yes, the colleague next gave a cool and clear solution. But I also value a different view of the problem and the effort of the person :)

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski In my solution you can use a list to as `list_final.extend(list_pool[0])`.  I forgot to have the results formatted as a list of tuples, which can be modified easily.  The results, `list_pool` is a list of lists due to how `list_data` was sliced based on the segment length.